# Tor unexpectedly exited when I started using terminal

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 14.04 when I use this to  sh start-tor-browser it won't start

[image: Screenshot of desktop]

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: you need the error that are displayed in terminal

Comment: Plese open a terminal and run `start-tor-browser` as you mentioned, but copy the output from the terminal and add it to the question. To write the output to a file you can do something like: `./start-tor-browser.sh | tee logfile`.

Comment: Lots of possible things could have gone wrong here. One possibility is that you're suffering from https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13717 -- you need to start tor browser as "./start-tor-browser", not as "sh start-tor-browser". The former lets it use bash as the shell (like it wants to), whereas the latter forces it to use sh as the shell, which might not be compatible.

Comment: it requires to be run as the user whom owns the files/folders sudo chown -R $(whoami) ./tor-browser*

Comment: I had the same error message. I was using a hidden service and forgot, that I set a log file and tor logging mode to "debug", which filled my log file to become ~2.81 GiB big. I emptied the log file and set logging mode to notice - Tor started to work again.

Answer (score 1):

On my debian/ubuntu style linux workstation, I can just click on the icon without having to run it from the command line. If I did want to run it from the command line and experienced this error, I would start by looking at the permissions and make sure the file is executable. If the file is not executable that is the problem right there....

```
root@r2:/home/august/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US# ls
Browser  Data  Docs  start-tor-browser  Tor
root@r2:/home/august/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US# ll start*
-rwx------ 1 august august 7588 1999-12-31 16:00 start-tor-browser*
root@r2:/home/august/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US# chmod a+x start-tor-browser
root@r2:/home/august/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US#
```

also I would check to make sure the user you are logged in as has ownership of the executable, or an easier way would be to 'sudo su' and run the executable as root, thats not the way you would normally run it but if it works when loged in as root you know that it is a permission issue. Although it will still not run if it is not marked executable.

If none of that helps the next thing I would do is open a terminal and review your log files:

```
   root@r2:~# cd /var/log
root@r2:/var/log# tail -f ./*.log
```

This will give you a scrolling output from all the logfiles. With that window still open and scrolling, try and open the tor browser bundle by clicking on it, and watch for error messages in the window. To stop the scrolling do crtl + c

Whatever is causing your error will probably show up in the logfiles. If you still can't figure it out, post the output from the logfiles here and we will have a look.

Nice wallpaper btw! Is that Kali?

`

Comment: it's not working hanging